# How to find value from Google sheet using multiple cell values and send email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I want to find the particular values in a google sheet, once its found then fetch total row values and send email from google sheet with the total row values.

I'm aware of send email from google-sheet but finding the particular value based on that send email is very challenging for me.

Wherever `E60` is present the should fetch total row values and need to send email.

Comment: Can you provide your current script and the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0):

To send a email via google sheet you will need to write some code with **script editor**. I think you could find more details [here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/google-sheets-send-email-based-on-cell-value/)

Answer (score 0):

After studying your question, I assume the following:

- You want to check a column matching the string `E60`.
- When a cell with `E60` is found, your want to send a email with the full row content.

If my assumptions are correct, you can use the following example to fulfill your requests:

#### CODE

```js
function E60Alert() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '{SPREADSHEET ID}').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var subject = "E60 Alert";
  var email = "{YOUR EMAIL}";
  var rowContent = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    if (rowContent[i - 1][4] == 'E60') {
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, rowContent[i - 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

#### BEHAVIOUR

That code will first read the full table. After that, it will iterate it searching for the desired string (`E60` in this case). If it finds it, it will send an email with the full row content.

#### OBSERVATIONS

- This code will run on demand by clicking the `Run` button.
- You will have to edit the `if (rowContent[i - 1][4] == 'E60') {` line to match the desired column of the data. I chose the fifth column (number 4) for testing purposes.

#### ALLUSIONS

- [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) & [`getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)
- [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) & [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [`sendEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailto,-replyto,-subject,-body)

Please take this as one of the possible solutions to your issue, and don't hesitate to write me back with any additional doubts or requests to further clarifications.